# AngularJS format big numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, numbers, format

I have a table with numbers, are really bigs, so I'm looking for something to format that numbers like $13b, $10m ...

Somebody has made this before and has something to do it? like  a customized filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This helped me, helps you too.

```
var lazyround = function (num) {
var parts = num.split(",");
return parts.length > 1 ? (Math.round(parseInt(parts.join(""), 10) / Math.pow(1000, parts.length-1)) + " " + ["thousand", "million", "billion"][parts.length-2]) : parts[0];
```

};

there you have a working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8pfB/

Answer (score -2):

why you don' t just sa ve this number as a string?

`var myBigNumbers = ['121394819394814818419391393901', ...]`